# How to validate an XML file against a schema using Visual Studio 2005

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xslt, visual-studio-2005

Is it possible to validate an xml file against its associated schema using Visual Studio 2005 IDE?

I could only see options to create a schema based on the current file, or show the XSLT output

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's done automatically, errors appear as warnings in the "Error List" and are additionally underlined with the blue squiggle in the source file.

Not sure if there is another way to validate the file, but this will do for now.

Comment: As long as your xml schema is set to the schema file, it should validate it automatically and any error will be detected.  You'll get the benefit of XML intellisense as well if you have a schema associated with the xml.

Comment: sorry.. How is this an answer?  Ok.. just remember???  If I needed to remember then at one point I would have known.

Answer (score 0):

[XmlSchemaValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemavalidator.aspx)

Warning: It's not pretty to use.

Comment: I should have clarified I wanted to use the IDE and not code.